# How do I delete a dict item that is a 'NoneType'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, collections

I'm making a program that takes salesforce reports, iteraters through them and displays them in a flask app.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import csv
import collections
app = Flask(__name__)
# odict_keys(['Edit', 'Activity ID', 'Assigned', 'Subject', 'Last Modified Date', 'Date', 'Priority'
# , 'Status', 'Company / Account', 'Created By', 'Activity Type', 'Comments'])


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():

    reports = {}
    with open('./reports/report040717.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in reader:

            temp = {row['Activity ID']: {'subject': row['Subject'], 'due_date': row['Date'], 'last_modified': row['Last Modified Date'], 'status': row['Status'],
                                         'company': row['Company / Account'], 'type': row['Activity Type'], 'comments': row['Comments']}}
            reports.update(temp)

    reports = collections.OrderedDict(reversed(list(reports.items())))

    for k, v in reports.items():
        print(k, v)

    return render_template('home.html', reports=reports)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I'm storing all of the rows read into a dictionary, then push that dictionary into another dictionary with the ID as the key.

The problem is I keep getting an empty dictionary and I can't figure out how to delete it.
This is how its showing up when im printing the k ,v values before calling the render

```
None {'subject': None, 'due_date': None, 'last_modified': None, 'status': None, 'company': None, 'type': None, 'comments': None}
```

and this is how all of the other shows up

```
00TF000003Ti9iE {'subject': 'some text', 'due_date': '4/18/2017', 'last_modified': '8/23/2016', 'status': 'Not Started', 'company': 'some text', 'type': 'some text', 'comments': 'some text'}
```

Any suggestions on how to delete the None entry in the report dict?

Comment: Should reports be a list instead of the dictionary? When you call reports.update you are not adding new information to the reports dictionary but rather replacing old information with new information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would imagine your reading in empty rows from your CSV file. You can do the following so those empty rows aren't loaded into the dictionary at all:

```
if row['Activity ID'] and row['Subject']:
    # row will only be added if the values above aren't None
    temp = {row['Activity ID']: {'subject': row['Subject'], 'due_date': row['Date'], 'last_modified': row['Last Modified Date'], 'status': row['Status'],
                                     'company': row['Company / Account'], 'type': row['Activity Type'], 'comments': row['Comments']}}
    reports.update(temp)
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much, I was going crazy trying to fix that.

Comment: Np! Accepting my answer would be much appreciated :)

Comment: 2 minutes and I will!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put anything in the larger dictionary that contains only None as values. My original code was incorrect this is TemporalWolf's suggested fix.

```
if(None not in temp):
    reports.update(temp)
```

Comment: Python allows `if temp is not None:` no parenthesis needed... and that won't work, as temp is a dictionary which contains `None` answers, not `None` itself. `if temp:` would check it's truthiness, but because it's populated with `None`s, it's length is non-zero and therefore it would still end up evaluating true.

Comment: You are correct I misread part of the question. Fixed to working code

Comment: You still use way more parenthesis than you need :) : `if None not in temp.values():` but I think you'll find that still doesn't work `temp.values()` is a single value: `{'subject': None, 'due_date': None, 'last_modified': None, 'status': None, 'company': None, 'type': None, 'comments': None}`. I'd recommend instead `if None not in temp:` as `in dict` defaults to listing their keys, which will test whether `row['Activity ID']` was `None`.

Comment: I always put parentheses for if statements although I realize they aren't necessary. temp.values() is an array of None values. I tested in advance to see if it would work.

Comment: Look again at `temp`. It is a dict containing a single key value pair. the value is another dict, containing string to value entries, of the format `{k : {sk: sv, sk2: sv2, ...}}`

Comment: I agree your idea of `None not in temp` is better.  I also clearly need to read more carefully. Updating